# proftpd umask and owners

Tags: permissions, apache2, proftpd

I am not a sysadmin, so my knowledge is limited in this topic.

We have an apache with some virtualhosts. For some reason, the group of the files and directories is a `gitusers`, because we are using hooks on commit sometimes. Sometimes not, but I would like keep this.

Owner of files is www-data.

I've created a new ftp user (a real linux user), called: `printftp` without  shell.

I've added this `printftp` user to the `gitusers` group.

Let's say, the directory of our http project is `/var/www/print.example.com/www/`

This is the home directory for `printftp`.

My problem is, all the new files created by this user will be: `printftp:printftp`

Is it possible to focrce the proftpd to inherit the owner and group from the `/var/www/print.example.com/www/`?

So all new files created by anyone should be: `www-data:gitusers`

And I also want to change 664 for files, and 775 for directories.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could create an extra file: `/etc/proftpd/conf.d/printftp.conf` with following configuration:

```
Umask                002  002
RequireValidShell    off
DefaultRoot          ~
UseReverseDNS        off

<IfModule mod_cap.c>
  CapabilitiesEngine off
</IfModule>

<Directory /var/www/print.example.com/www/>
  UserOwner   www-data
  GroupOwner  www-data
</Directory>
```

First part is the umask for your permissions, and second part is for setting the permissions. It's possible you need to tweak the config according to your needs.

Comment: I put the file, and set real path. nem of file is the [username].conf and put it into the dir. Restarted the daemond, but no change.

In my proftd.conf there is a line: `Include /etc/proftpd/conf.d/` Should I add my new file individally?

Comment: Nope, If I do mistake, when I restart I got error.  So it reads it, but has no effect

Comment: Can you run proftp in foreground in debug modus? First stop the service and then run it with `sudo proftpd -d10 -n -c /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf`.
Put 1 file and look in the console. In my log I see `root chown(/test.log) to uid 1000, gid 1000 successful`

Comment: check http://vaso.hu/tmp/ Last line is the file.

Comment: Can you give me the output of `egrep -v "^#|^$" /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf  /etc/proftpd/conf.d/*.log`

Comment: For 1 week: https://pastebin.com/HQMsUgYW

Comment: And the files in `/etc/proftpd/conf.d/`?

Comment: Yes, and as I sad, it should definitely read it. I made intentionally a syntax error in the `conf.d/printerftp.conf`  and when I tried to restart the daemon, it sad errors. I removed the syntax error, restart, and that was ok.

Comment: what is the content of `printerftp.conf`?